# How to get multiple of same rows given a list of possible duplicate ids?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Lets say i have an array of ids like this:

```
[102, 102, 103, 104]
```

How would i get rows corresponding to each element in the array. In this example, it should also return two rows with id 102

This is my current code, but it only returns unique rows:

```
        const variants = await this.db.variants.findAll({
            where: {
                variant_id: variant_ids,
            },
            include: {
                model: this.db.products_has_variants,
                as: 'products_has_variants',
                include: {
                    model: this.db.products,
                    as: 'product',
                },
            },
        });
```

I know that a working solution like this would work:

```
const new_variants = variant_ids.flatMap(id => variants.filter(variant => variant.variant_id === id));
```

Comment: Use a `JOIN` of the list against the table, not a `WHERE` condition

Comment: @Bergi it wont make a difference related to my question. However i have a db configuration with the column relations. This automatically makes joins based on my queries when i use "include"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findAll()` does not support that kind of duplicated results by default, and your solution has `O(n^2)` complexity.

We can add two statements to make it `O(n)`:

```
const variantsMap = variants.reduce((acc, curr) => ({ ...acc, [curr.id]: curr }), {});
const newVariants = variantIds.map(id => variantsMap[id]);
```

##### Side note

You could try setting `raw: true` in the query to stop `findAll` from deduplicating the results but I wouldn't recommend it even if it works.

Comment: i tried raw: true, but it does not work as i expected. Using map is probably the easiest solution:)

Comment: Repeatedly spreading the object still has `O(n²)` time complexity. You'll want to use `new Map` or `Object.fromEntries` instead.

Comment: @Bergi spreading objects has a time complexity of O(n)

Comment: @EliasKnudsen And it's done in a `reduce` loop, making it n squared